# JavaScript : How to move a window to specified location in Microsoft EDGE browser?

Tags: javascript, window, microsoft-edge

As per the Microsoft release update [EDGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467845(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Window objects associated with frames are no longer affected by
>   moveTo, moveBy, resizeTo, or resizeBy

In this case , How can we move a window to the desired location through JavaScript?

My code which is working across all browsers IE 11, Firefox, Chrome but not with EDGE.

```
var newWindow = window.open(url,'name','width=250,height=150');
newWindow.moveTo(800,300);  // this doesn't work with EDGE
```

**Edit :**  Tried setting position directly on window.open but no success

```
var newWindow = window.open(url,'name','width=250,height=150,left=800,top=300');// This also doesnt work with EDGE
```

Comment: HI Jaromanda ,,Thanks for replying back ..Actually mine is a simple requirement. I just use window.open with features inside and then window.moveTO to set the position of the opened window . But this is not working with EDGE browser alone and seems they officially announced that these functions wont work with window

Comment: Works fine in EDGE for me

Comment: Ah , I envy you :) What is the EDGE version that you are using ?Also, if you change the moveTo() input values you are able to see the change in position as well ?

Comment: Is the window that you are trying to move associated with a frame?

Comment: `window.open('url', 'name', 'width=250,height=150,left=1200,top=1200')` does not work either. Hmm.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin No Shaun . Its not